# PayPal Adaptive Payments REST API or classic?

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I developed a website that is currently using PayPal Adaptive Payments to manage transactions between different users. I saw that paypal is renewing apis from classic to rest apis. It is really complicated to understand all that stuff. My question is about Adaptive Payments classic api...is there already a rest api that substitutes adaptive payments classic or not? Is there any better system to allow dynamic payments between different users?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: if your website already uses Adaptive Payments and is meeting your needs there's no compelling reason to switch. The Adaptive Payments APIs will do most of the things PayPal's other, competing APIs do, and some things those APIs won't. Only change if you're redoing your site anyway, or you need specific functionality the current APIs don't offer. You havn't listed any specific gap or need in your question so I can't say more.

Background: broadly speaking, **PayPal has developed three generations of APIs**:

- The **original set**, including products like Express Checkout, are
  pretty squarly focused on web (and mobile) "checkout", the dominant
  paradigm of a decade ago for the purchase of goods and services on a
  merchant site.
- The **second set**, which includes Adaptive Payments, was
  intended to be more flexible (hence the "Adaptive" name) and address
  payments that might not be "just" checkouts. For example
  multi-merchant marketplaces.
- The **third set** is PayPal's RESTful APIs,
  which are designed primarily as a technology refresh to replace
  earlier APIs. The RESTful APIs are still being developed and do not
  yet offer all the functions of the previous APIs, but are likely to
  get more investment and development going forward; as such -- and
  because they use newer, more industry-current integration styles --
  they may be a good choice for new integrations.

(I work for PayPal and wrote a chunk of the first API set but am not an official company spokesperson, so consider this informed but not authoritative.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I was reviewing my website structure and I found that my adaptive payments files are very messed up. Another problem is that in adaptive payments, paypal displays my name and surname instead of a "company name" but I'm working on a startup without VAT so I cannot register an account for a company that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: This is a PayPal account type difference, not really particular to adaptive payments. In Payal parlance a "personal" or "premier" account is owned by (and identified by/as) an individual; a "business" account is expected to be owned by (and identified as) a company. I can't speak to the particular legal hoops of setting up a company in your jurisdiction, but if you want to test that PayPal will behave as intended with a business account you should be able to easily create a fake business account in the PayPal sandbox.

Comment: Thanks for this explainer- Paypal API docs are such a cluster, with functional overlap and no clear indication of what supersedes what. They should just slap version numbers on their APIs like everybody else.